# read a path from a config.properties file

Tags: java

I have a file named `config.properties` in Eclipse with the following content:

```
PATH_TO_A_FILE=a.txt
PATH_TO_B_FILE=b.txt
PATH_TO_C_FILE=c.txt
```

In my code, I need to use these properties like this:

```
conf.put("PATH_TO_B_FILE", properties.getProperty("PATH_TO_B_FILE"));
```

which files A.txt and B.txt are in the same path of the config.properties in the workspace folder

What I should do read those paths from my `config.properties` file?

Also: should I add a path before `b.txt`? 
Should I write it as `/home/user/workspace/b.txt` or `.home.user.Dersktop.b.txt`?

Comment: If you put relative path (b.txt, ../b.txt, src/main/resources/b.txt), it will take relative path. If you put full path(/usr/b.txt, /root/b.txt, /b.txt), it will take full path. So, it's depend on your settings. But, `.home.user.Dersktop` is not valid path, because, it's (maybe) internal path-resolver of Eclipse which is not appliable for Java

Comment: thanks for your reply , i solved it

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have a file with path `/home/user/Desktop/my.conf` that contains properties, then you can load these properties in a `Properties` object like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/home/user/Desktop/my.conf");
properties.load(input);
```

Now you can get the properties like this:

```
String pathToA = properies.get("PATH_TO_A_FILE");
```

Obviously, you shouldn't put that properties file `my.conf` on your desktop. Are you creating a web app? In that case, you can ship the properties file with your jar. Files can be read from a jar using an `InputStream`, but that's a different question ;-)

Whether or not you should add a full path in the properties file also depends on the context of your application. In a server environment, you may not have a `/home/user/Desktop` directory. If you want an answer to that second question, you should clarify the context of your question. For instance: is your application a desktop or server application? what is the working directory of your application?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I would use the *relative* path to the file. Imagine this: you put your web application in a jar and you deploy it on a server. The application server where your jar is deployed probably won't have access to `/home/user/workspace/myproject/a.txt`. It is much better to put `a.txt` in your jar and load the file from the jar.

Comment: I don't understand the additional question. Did you try anything? If so, did it work? What kind of answer do you expect? Seems like you're wasting time on a non-issue...

Comment: OK, so you create the files in the working directory. In that case, why wouldn't you use relative paths. I really don't see the issue. Maybe there is no issue. Maybe you just haven't tried anything yet...

Comment: English is not my tonuge language i'm trying to write with it  !! i think too it's not very bad as you wrote so be careful not to taunt anyone ?? i think i post my  problem  but you cannot understand it ! so thanks for your time and if you coudln't help or understand me or complete your answer ... don't reply

Comment: You want to read a path from a configuration file. That's very easy to achieve. However: you seem to have a problem. Otherwise you wouldn't post a question. Unfortunately, you don't succeed in explaining the problem. The fact that nobody but me tries to help you should be an indication that you should do a better effort explaining what goes wrong. Does anything go wrong? Please explain!

Comment: I guess I was right when I wrote: *Maybe you just haven't tried anything yet...* ;-) That wasn't a reason to down-vote my answer, wouldn't you say?